# How do one solve a nonlinear combinatoric problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I am an undergraduate CS student and I am struggling with a problem.

$Qx = b$ where $Q$ is a constant $m \times n$ matrix (with $m>n$), $x$ is a $n \times 1$ vector and $b$ is a $m\times 1$ vector.

I want to maximize the number of zeros in vector $b$.

subject to: $x(i)>0$ for $i=1,2, \ldots,n$

How do one tackle a problem like this ?

Comment: Does this mean you want a $Q$ that will give you the most zeroes in the *image* of $Q$?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Q is a constant matrix. I added this detail to the question now. 
I want to generate x vectors with all positive elements that maximize the number of zeros in vector b.

Comment: Why is this non-linear?

Comment: You could start by checking if $Q$ is singular (that is, its determinant is $0$). If so, then find the nullspace of $Q$. As for if it's not singular...I'm still working on that.

Comment: @Raskolnikov the function I am try to optimize (number of zeros) is nonlinear.

Comment: Do you happen to have an idea of how big $m$ and $n$ are?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Q is an m by n matrix where m is not equal to n. Therefore it is not invertible.

Comment: @Alex n is a number like 4,5,6; not a big number. m is 2^n.

Comment: I've corrected the question; if $x$ and $b$ were to be of the same size, then $Q$ would have to be square, which visibly it is not supposed to be. I've also added $m>n$, as this may help to fix ideas about the nature of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no guarantee that you will be able to create any zeros at all, for instance if all entries of $Q$ are strictly positive. So a first thing I would do is to forget about those coordinates $b_j$ that cannot ever be made zero, namely those for which row $j$ of $Q$ does not have both a positive and a negative entry (this includes the rows that are entirely zero, which are uninteresting for a different reason). Then for each remaining row you've got a linear equation in $x$ that gives the condition for that coordinate to become zero, and which is such that the hyperplane of its solutions meets the strictly positive cone given by $x_i>0$ for all $i$. Now the task is to find the largest collection of rows so that the intersection of their solution hyperplanes still meets that cone. You might search for sets of $n$ rows whose equations are linearly dependent, as that is a necessary condition for having a collection of at least $n$ coordinates that can be made zero simultaneously. It there are no sets of $n$ linearly dependent rows, then you just need to find the largest collection of at most $n-1$ rows whose intersection of hyperplanes meets the positive cone. If sets of $n$ linearly dependent rows do exist, you could check their intersection of hyperplanes, and see if it meets the positive cone; if it does you can get those $n$ coordinates to be zero, if it doesn't then that set of $n$ linearly dependent rows is not productive after all. You are probably left with a few productive $n$-tuples at best, which you might compare to see if even more than $n$ simultaneous zeros can be achieved.

Comment: I don't understand how linearly dependent rows of $Q$, lead to zero elements in $b$.
We multiply a row of $Q$ with $x$ and get an element of $b$. So how does the linear dependence effect the # of zeros in $b$ ?

Comment: I'm not saying linearly dependent rows lead to zero elements in $b$ directly. Every row with both positive and negative entries gives an entry that _can_ be made zero, and the possibilities for doing so (ignoring the positivity restrictions) define a hyperplane in the parameter space. For linearly _independent_ rows the dimension of the intersection of those spaces drops for each one of them, and an $n$-tuple of them leaves nothing as intersection. So linear dependence gives some _hope_ of having $n$ simultaneous zeros, but no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slow way to do it.

- Find a parametrization for $\operatorname{Nul} Q$, and see if it contains a positive vector (which is a matter of examining some inequalities that fall out of the parametrization). If so, this is such an $x$.
- Failing that, one at a time, check if each standard basis vector $e_i$ is in $\operatorname{Col} Q$. If it is, Find a parametrization of $Q^{-1}e_i$ (the preimage of $e_i$ - not implying that $Q$ is invertible here), and again see if it contains a positive vector. If so, this is such an $x$.
- Failing that, one at a time, find a parametrization of $Q^{-1}\operatorname{Span}(e_i,e_j)$, and again see if it contains a positive vector. If so, this is such an $x$.
- Continue with $Q^{-1}\operatorname{Span}(e_i,e_j,e_k)$, etc.

Comment: Given that the dimension of the codomain space is much larger than the domain, the map is likely to be injective and highly non-surjective. Then most of the things tried here will give nothing useful (the nullspace has dimension $0$, and any particular nonzero vector is unlikely to be in the image).

Comment: @Marc Is your comment more a note for the OP that the optimal $x$ is likely to yield zero 0's? This would be a very slow approach, but I think it's exhaustive. Although I did just edit it realizing that I meant to refer to spans.

Answer (score 0):

For any given subset $S$ of $\{1\ldots m\}$, making $b_j = 0$ for all $j \in S$ corresponds to solving
$Q_S x = 0, x > 0$ where $Q_S$ is the submatrix of $Q$ corresponding to the rows in $S$.  By homogeneity, if there is a solution there will be one with all $x_j \ge 1$.
Linear programming software may be helpful.

Of course there may be a lot of subsets to consider.  Fortunately, you didn't ask
for an efficient solution.

Comment: I don't understand that there will be a solution with all $x_j\geq 1$. In comments, OP indicates $m=2^n$. So consider a $4\times2$ matrix of all 1s. There is a null space $\operatorname{Span}(1,-1)$. With $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ we have that $Q_S=Q$ and all nonzero solutions to $Q_Sx=0$ have at least one negative coordinate.

Comment: I suppose by $x>0$ you mean every component of $x$ is strictly positive (as opposed to non-negative with at least one of them nonzero, i.e., $x\geq0$ and $x\neq0$, which is how I would be inclined to interpret it).

Comment: @alex.jordan: The answer says "_if_ there is a solution..."; in you example there isn't.

Comment: @Marc, Oh I see, I read it as "if there is a solution to the _equation_".

Comment: Is there any linear programming software you would recommend for this problem ?

Comment: Recommendation might depend on how big $m$ and $n$ are, what other mathematical software you use, what else you might use the software for, ....  There is lots of free stuff available.